# how to add radius and color for location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails

I'm new on gmap4rails gem
I see this in wiki https://github.com/apneadiving/Google-Maps-for-Rails/wiki/Circles

But when i try it with my code 
i place this

```
  def index
    @ads = Ad.all
    @hash = Gmaps4rails.build_markers(@ads) do |ads, marker|
  marker.lat ads.latitude
  marker.lng ads.longitude
  marker.infowindow ads.name
  end
@circles_json = '[
 {"lng": -122.214897, "lat": 37.772323, "radius": 1000000},
 //you can add whatever customization within the hash
 {"lng": 122.214897, "lat": 37.772323, "radius": 1000000, "strokeColor": "#FF0000"}
]'
  end
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
  handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
   markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);
   circle = handler.addMarkers(<%= gmaps({"circles"=> { "data" => @circles_json }})%>);
   handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
   handler.fitMapToBounds();

 });
</script>
```

and file application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
//= require_tree .
```

and got this issue
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPJPX.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    handler = Gmaps.build('Google');
    handler.buildMap({ provider: {}, internal: {id: 'map'}}, function(){
        markers = handler.addMarkers(<%=raw @hash.to_json %>);

        var circles = handler.addCircles(
            [
                {"lng": 122.214897, "lat": 37.772323, "radius": 1000000, "strokeColor": "#FF0000"}
            ]
        );

        handler.bounds.extendWith(markers);
        handler.bounds.extendWith(circles);
        handler.fitMapToBounds();

    });

</script>
```

Comment: this work ,but i still want why my gmaps method error :( ,thank you. Can i add you to my project ? you can help me ?

Comment: how can i contact with you ?

Comment: Do you want to hire my for your project then upwork is good option.

Answer (score 0):

Have you inserted google scripts in your dom?

Have you added following line in application.js?

```
//= require underscore
//= require gmaps/google
```

Comment: I've added it before

Comment: have you added or used any gmap helper method? It might be conflict with plugin method.